# Networking for CoC-like mobile games

Tags: networking, mobile, real-time, game-development

We are wondering what's a good networking design for mobile games that have real time single player battles like Clash of Clans.

One option is to do the battle completely on client side, and send the result back to the server when the battle is done. However it seems this will allow cheating. Is there any security model to handle this? Technically hackers can do anything that your client can do, so

The other option is to do real time networking between client and server. But I'm not sure whether this is a good idea for mobile games considering various network conditions.

Does anyone know what's a good design here? How does Clash of Clans do it?

Answer (score 0):

Until CoC developer officially speak about it, it won't be known well. I my thoughts, CoC is somehow free from cheating because it allows attacked players to see the replay of what the attackers did to them.

Doing real time networking is best for preventing from cheaters, but it will annoy some game players because Wifi and LTE network occur 40~150ms latency with 10~20% packet loss. Moreover, CoC game play will give game servers much load for running A* algorithm for each mob character. Unlike League of Legends, the navigation path in CoC is changed as each Wall is broken, so O(1) by adopting path table technique is not feasible.